# Releasing mediaplayer and stopping it onPause and onResume gives error in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, video-streaming, android-videoview

i m using videoView and mediaplayer but stopping mediaplayer in onPause and onResume gives me error:

```
 static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 private VideoViewCustom videoView;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailvideo);
        context = this;
        videoView = (VideoViewCustom) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
        //initialize media player
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d(TAG,"setOnPreparedListener");
                mediaPlayer = mp;
                int timeDuration = 0;
                boolean videoPlaying = false;
                if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"savedInstanceState != null");
                    timeDuration = savedInstanceState.getInt("timeduration");
                    videoPlaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("videoPlaying");
                    Log.d(TAG, "timeDuration saved:" + timeDuration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "videoPlaying saved:" + videoPlaying);
                    Log.d(TAG,"video position:"+videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                    if (videoPlaying) {
                        videoView.seekTo(timeDuration);
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        videoView.start();
                    } else {
                        videoView.seekTo(timeDuration);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "savedInstanceState == null");
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    videoView.start();
                }

                finalTime = videoView.getDuration();
                Log.d(TAG, "mp.getCurrentPosition():" + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                Date d = new Date(videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                String time = sdf.format(d).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "time:" + time);
                videoSeekBar.setProgress(timeDuration);
                videoSeekBar.setMax(finalTime);
               durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime,1000);
            }
        });
}
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Setup the player
        videoView.resume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();

    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 backArrowImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null)

                {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
}
```

**once i press backArrowImageView button i have written code above my app crashed and giving me this logcat** :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop(MediaPlayer.java:1561)
        at com.ui.VideoDetailActivity.onPause(VideoDetailActivity.java:493)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5686)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1239)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3347)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:171)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

VideoDetailActivity.java:493  contains:  
         mediaPlayer.stop();      inside onPause method ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Android documentation:

> "IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been
>   initialized or has been released."

So ensure your MediaPlayer is initialized, and you don't use the released one.
Use like below in onPause() and onDestroy(),

```
try{
    if(mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
       Log.d("TAG------->", "player is running");
       mediaPlayer.stop();
       Log.d("Tag------->", "player is stopped");
       mediaPlayer.release();
       Log.d("TAG------->", "player is released");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States) you MUST avoid calling `stop()` in `IDLE`, `INITIALIZED` or `ERROR` states of MediaPlayer.

`release()` and `reset()` API can be called in any state of MediaPlayer.

Unfortunately to find out current state you have to track it yourself (there is no API for that). In one of my project I create class which extend MediaPlayer and by overriding some of MediaPlayer API track it's current state, so I can easily check current state before invoking any API. If you invoke API in incorrect state usually state changes to `ERROR` and you have to re-initialize media player again to fix it.

Comment: the below answer will work ? and how can i know tht i m in incorrect stage ?

Comment: You have to manage state's by yourself. There is table of MediaPlayer state machine in official docs. According to this table you need to save current MediaPlayer state in some variable and change it when you call some of player API.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this...u need to check for null and u cant Stop a Non Playing Media so check for Playing too before you release or Stop

```
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: how can i  realease mediaplayer once i finish  activity ? @rajan ks

Comment: Unless `mediaPlayer != null` ,u can perform `stop(),release() and reset()`on it,i was mentioning about `onPause()` method

Answer (score -1):

before realeasing mediaplayer . use this line of code

```
mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Here an example .**

```
try{
    video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mp.reset();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;                       
    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Releasing mp", e.toString());
    }
```