# Android MediaPlayer class throws java.lang.IllegalStateException after activity resumed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I'm trying to pause and resume VideoView with MediaPlayer in activity onPause() and onResume() methods, but in onResume() method MediaPlayer throws java.lang.IllegalStateException. I didn't release MediaPlayer but I think MediaPlayer automatically released after activity paused.
How should I handle it?

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

void prepareVideo() {
    videoView = new VideoView(context.getApplicationContext());
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + 
    R.raw.my_video;
    videoView.setVideoPath(path);
}

videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer = mp;
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

The exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1194)
    at co.myapp.app.reborn.myappTestActivity.onResume(myappTestActivity.java:370)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6347)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3152) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1400) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:734) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
```

Comment: In your onPause, super should be first..did you try that...??

Comment: refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32644621/6454463)

Comment: The result is same, @Mangal

Comment: What is the source file?Is it local or over network or in raw?

Comment: The problem occurs on resuming video when activity resumed, @rutvik-bhatt

Comment: Is it getting played initially?

Comment: yes, it's play without any problem @Mangal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to implement MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener interface and set MediaPlayer in onSeekComplete method.

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onSeekComplete(final MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer = mp;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this info?

Comment: I don't remember but it was working. probably by trial and error. Is there any problem with this approach? @VadimKotov

Comment: Yeah, did not work for me for some reason. The error was still the same

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the mediaplayer state diagram on android documentation

[MediaPlayer state diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram)

According to the diagram you have to call setDataSource() and prepare() before calling start().

Probably something wrong happened before. Your logcat should point you in the right direction.

My guess is that your mediaplayer is not in paused state but in stopped state. So you have to call prepare and then start, not just start.

Unfortunately in this way your playback will restart from scratch.

You can use seek command for resuming a position saved during the activity pausing.

Comment: I'm using VideoView, I never use setDataSource(currentConext, url), this method is called internally in VideoView class.

Comment: ok ... so I guess that the issue is related to the "stopped" state of the media player

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue yesterday and I'd like to share my experience facing this issue, the root cause and the fix in my particular issue; this might be helpful for someone else.

This is what I found in my particular issue.

1. I´m running MediaPlayer in Fragment
2. When the phone goes to sleep (black screen), in the fragment-life-cycle the stop() function is call.
3. MediaPlayer recommends to release() MediaPlayer resources on STOP state.
4. When the phone resumes, it complains with illegal-state-exception because there are no MediaPlayer resource available, remember it was released in the STOPE state.

So, to fix it. I overrided start() state and I got another instance of MediaPlayer if it was null at that specific point in time. START state is called at resume time.

sample code

```
public class xMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer
{
    private static xMediaPlayer instance = null;

    public static xMediaPlayer getInstance( )
    {
        if( instance == null )
            instance = new xMediaPlayer( );

        return instance;
    }      
}
```

Override start() on fragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();      
    mMediaPlayer = xMediaPlayer.getInstance( );
}
```